# Gitlab not picking up jobs from .gitlab-ci.yml on new projects

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Gitlab not picking up jobs from .gitlab-ci.yml on new projects
There seems to be a problem with my CI/CD pipelines as they don’t appear to be picking up jobs/stages from the configuration. I’m using the same configuration as I do on all my Java-based projects and for existing projects on Gitlab it’s fine and it picks up the job but for any new projects it will only run the first build stage

```
# Auto DevOps
# This CI/CD configuration provides a standard pipeline for
# * building a Docker image (using a buildpack if necessary),
# * storing the image in the container registry,
# * running tests from a buildpack,
# * running code quality analysis,
# * creating a review app for each topic branch,
# * and continuous deployment to production
#
# Test jobs may be disabled by setting environment variables:
# * test: TEST_DISABLED
# * code_quality: CODE_QUALITY_DISABLED
# * license_management: LICENSE_MANAGEMENT_DISABLED
# * performance: PERFORMANCE_DISABLED
# * load_performance: LOAD_PERFORMANCE_DISABLED
# * sast: SAST_DISABLED
# * secret_detection: SECRET_DETECTION_DISABLED
# * dependency_scanning: DEPENDENCY_SCANNING_DISABLED
# * container_scanning: CONTAINER_SCANNING_DISABLED
# * dast: DAST_DISABLED
# * review: REVIEW_DISABLED
# * stop_review: REVIEW_DISABLED
#
# In order to deploy, you must have a Kubernetes cluster configured either
# via a project integration, or via group/project variables.
# KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN must also be set on the cluster settings,
# as a variable at the group or project level, or manually added below.
#
# Continuous deployment to production is enabled by default.
# If you want to deploy to staging first, set STAGING_ENABLED environment variable.
# If you want to enable incremental rollout, either manual or time based,
# set INCREMENTAL_ROLLOUT_MODE environment variable to "manual" or "timed".
# If you want to use canary deployments, set CANARY_ENABLED environment variable.
#
# If Auto DevOps fails to detect the proper buildpack, or if you want to
# specify a custom buildpack, set a project variable `BUILDPACK_URL` to the
# repository URL of the buildpack.
# e.g. BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git#v142
# If you need multiple buildpacks, add a file to your project called
# `.buildpacks` that contains the URLs, one on each line, in order.
# Note: Auto CI does not work with multiple buildpacks yet

image: alpine:latest

variables:
  STAGING_ENABLED: "true"
  POSTGRES_ENABLED: "false"

  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

  ROLLOUT_RESOURCE_TYPE: deployment

  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4501

  MIGRATE_HELM_2TO3: "true"
  AUTO_DEVOPS_FORCE_DEPLOY_V2: 1

stages:
  - make
  - build
  - deploy  # dummy stage to follow the template guidelines
  - review
  - dast
  - staging
  - canary
  - production
  - incremental rollout 10%
  - incremental rollout 25%
  - incremental rollout 50%
  - incremental rollout 100%
  - performance
  - cleanup

make:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
  stage: make
  script:
    - mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$BUILDPACK_URL || $AUTO_DEVOPS_EXPLICITLY_ENABLED == "1" || $DOCKERFILE_PATH'

    - exists:
        - Dockerfile

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure
    - exists:
        - project.clj

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go
    - exists:
        - go.mod
        - Gopkg.mod
        - Godeps/Godeps.json
        - vendor/vendor.json
        - glide.yaml
        - src/**/*.go

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle
    - exists:
        - gradlew
        - build.gradle
        - settings.gradle

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java
    - exists:
        - pom.xml
        - pom.atom
        - pom.clj
        - pom.groovy
        - pom.rb
        - pom.scala
        - pom.yaml
        - pom.yml

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi
    - exists:
        - .buildpacks

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
    - exists:
        - package.json

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
    - exists:
        - composer.json
        - index.php

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play
    # TODO: detect script excludes some scala files
    - exists:
        - '**/conf/application.conf'

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
    # TODO: detect script checks that all of these exist, not any
    - exists:
        - requirements.txt
        - setup.py
        - Pipfile

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
    - exists:
        - Gemfile

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala
    - exists:
        - '*.sbt'
        - project/*.scala
        - .sbt/*.scala
        - project/build.properties

    # https://github.com/dokku/buildpack-nginx
    - exists:
        - .static
# Auto DevOps
# This CI/CD configuration provides a standard pipeline for
# * building a Docker image (using a buildpack if necessary),
# * storing the image in the container registry,
# * running tests from a buildpack,
# * running code quality analysis,
# * creating a review app for each topic branch,
# * and continuous deployment to production
#
# Test jobs may be disabled by setting environment variables:
# * test: TEST_DISABLED
# * code_quality: CODE_QUALITY_DISABLED
# * license_management: LICENSE_MANAGEMENT_DISABLED
# * performance: PERFORMANCE_DISABLED
# * load_performance: LOAD_PERFORMANCE_DISABLED
# * sast: SAST_DISABLED
# * secret_detection: SECRET_DETECTION_DISABLED
# * dependency_scanning: DEPENDENCY_SCANNING_DISABLED
# * container_scanning: CONTAINER_SCANNING_DISABLED
# * dast: DAST_DISABLED
# * review: REVIEW_DISABLED
# * stop_review: REVIEW_DISABLED
#
# In order to deploy, you must have a Kubernetes cluster configured either
# via a project integration, or via group/project variables.
# KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN must also be set on the cluster settings,
# as a variable at the group or project level, or manually added below.
#
# Continuous deployment to production is enabled by default.
# If you want to deploy to staging first, set STAGING_ENABLED environment variable.
# If you want to enable incremental rollout, either manual or time based,
# set INCREMENTAL_ROLLOUT_MODE environment variable to "manual" or "timed".
# If you want to use canary deployments, set CANARY_ENABLED environment variable.
#
# If Auto DevOps fails to detect the proper buildpack, or if you want to
# specify a custom buildpack, set a project variable `BUILDPACK_URL` to the
# repository URL of the buildpack.
# e.g. BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git#v142
# If you need multiple buildpacks, add a file to your project called
# `.buildpacks` that contains the URLs, one on each line, in order.
# Note: Auto CI does not work with multiple buildpacks yet

image: alpine:latest

variables:
  STAGING_ENABLED: "true"
  # KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN is the application deployment domain and should be set as a variable at the group or project level.
  # KUBE_INGRESS_BASE_DOMAIN: domain.example.com
  POSTGRES_ENABLED: "false"

  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

  ROLLOUT_RESOURCE_TYPE: deployment

  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4501

  MIGRATE_HELM_2TO3: "true"
  AUTO_DEVOPS_FORCE_DEPLOY_V2: 1

stages:
  - make
  - build
  - deploy  # dummy stage to follow the template guidelines
  - review
  - dast
  - staging
  - canary
  - production
  - incremental rollout 10%
  - incremental rollout 25%
  - incremental rollout 50%
  - incremental rollout 100%
  - performance
  - cleanup

make:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
  stage: make
  script:
    - mvn clean package 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$BUILDPACK_URL || $AUTO_DEVOPS_EXPLICITLY_ENABLED == "1" || $DOCKERFILE_PATH'

    - exists:
        - Dockerfile

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-clojure
    - exists:
        - project.clj

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go
    - exists:
        - go.mod
        - Gopkg.mod
        - Godeps/Godeps.json
        - vendor/vendor.json
        - glide.yaml
        - src/**/*.go

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle
    - exists:
        - gradlew
        - build.gradle
        - settings.gradle

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java
    - exists:
        - pom.xml
        - pom.atom
        - pom.clj
        - pom.groovy
        - pom.rb
        - pom.scala
        - pom.yaml
        - pom.yml

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi
    - exists:
        - .buildpacks

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
    - exists:
        - package.json

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
    - exists:
        - composer.json
        - index.php

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-play
    # TODO: detect script excludes some scala files
    - exists:
        - '**/conf/application.conf'

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
    # TODO: detect script checks that all of these exist, not any
    - exists:
        - requirements.txt
        - setup.py
        - Pipfile

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
    - exists:
        - Gemfile

    # https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala
    - exists:
        - '*.sbt'
        - project/*.scala
        - .sbt/*.scala
        - project/build.properties

    # https://github.com/dokku/buildpack-nginx
    - exists:
        - .static


include:
  - template: Jobs/Build.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Build.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/DAST-Default-Branch-Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/DAST-Default-Branch-Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Jobs/Browser-Performance-Testing.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Browser-Performance-Testing.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Security/DAST.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/DAST.gitlab-ci.yml
  - remote: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/raw/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Helm-2to3.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Thanks for taking the time to be thorough in your request, it really helps! :blush:

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Please provide precise reproductions steps.

Comment: I don't think this is a Kubernetes issue but I'm running 1.19 and my Gitlab isn't self-hosted. The runners are also on Gitlab